# CSS doesn't get loaded in IE8, when deleting cache from WP Super Cache it works fine

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site that works fine in every browser but sometimes the CSS doesn't get loaded in IE8.

I think it has something to do with WP Super Cache. When I delete cache and open the website again it works perfectly. But after some time IE8 css doesn't get loaded anymore.

What is the problem? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Stop using the plugin or try using W3 Total Cache instead of the Super Cache plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that your theme checks the browser and based on that decides whether or not to load the IE8 CSS. In other words, it dynamically loads the CSS.

If it is, change that behavior. The plugin caches static HTML files, if that static file is not create for IE8, it would miss the IE8 css.

Changing to W3 Total Cache won't change that.